# how to get the 1st day of the year sql query oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a sql query to get a 1st day of the 1st month of the year which i am passing.

ex: If i am passing 2021, my output should be 01-JAN-2021
If i am passing 2020, my output should be 01-JAN-2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are passing the year as the bind variable `:year` then:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(:year||'0101','YYYYMMDD')
FROM   DUAL;
```

or

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE(:year,'YYYY'),'YY')
FROM   DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the year as a number, you can get the desired result with the following code:

```
with yy(yy) as (
  select 2021 from dual union all
  select 2020 from dual union all
  select 1970 from dual
)
select
  add_months(date'0000-01-01', yy * 12) y1,
  date'0000-01-01' + TO_YMINTERVAL(to_char(yy)||'-0') y2
from yy;
```

Result:

```
+------------+------------+
|     Y1     |     Y2     |
+------------+------------+
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1970-01-01 | 1970-01-01 |
+------------+------------+
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f62182f722f47e9ef9a934f9ab3cf006)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select trunc(sysdate,'YEAR') from dual;
```